# Accessing JSON via jQuery $.each

Tags: jquery, each

I have some JSON like:

```
response = [
  {"FIRSTNAME":"Richard","ACCOUNT":5555,"ID":"5056","LASTNAME":"Harris"},  
  {"FIRSTNAME":"Gary","ACCOUNT":4444,"ID":"DFC7","LASTNAME":"Coles"},
  {"FIRSTNAME":"Jeff","CORPORATEACCOUNT":3333,"ID":"7F31","LASTNAME":"Hopper"},
  {"FIRSTNAME":"Jack","ACCOUNT":2222,"ID":"E051","LASTNAME":"Canrell"},
  {"FIRSTNAME":"Tim","ACCOUNT":1111,"ID":"5056","LASTNAME":"Johns"}
]
```

I need to loop over it and display a row for each user, and my jQuery isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/my-controller/my-method?format=json",
    data: {id: id},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        var resultHtml = '';
        $.each(response, function(i, response) {
            $.each(response, function(property, value) {
            resultHtml += value + '\n';
        });
        });

        alert(resultHtml);
    }
});
```

So this echos out:

```
Richard
5555
5056
Harris
Gary
4444
DFC7
Coles
etc.
etc.
etc.
```

The JSON is being returns from the controller but how do I loop through and get this?

```
Richard harris 5555 5056
Gary Coles 4444 DFC7
Jeff Hopper 3333 7F31
Jack Canrell 2222 E051
Tim Johns 1111 5060
```

Comment: item.FIRSTNAME+" "+item.ACCOUNT....

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to `$.each` a 2nd time.  You have an object, just use the fields you want.

```
$.each(response, function(i, value) {
    resultHtml += value.FIRSTNAME + value.LASTNAME + value.ACCOUNT + value.ID + '\n';
});
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Is there an easy way to make my JSON names lowercase?

Comment: @TimPiele: How are you generating it?  Try fixing the case there.

Comment: @TimPiele: You *could* loop through and make a new object with lower case keys, if you really wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON first, try JSON.parse(response); to have it create an object you can iterate over.

Comment: i thought dataType: "json" took care of that?

Comment: your right, sorry... and Rocket Hazmat beat me to the right answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/my-controller/my-method?format=json",
    data: {id: id},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        var resultHtml = '';
        $.each(response, function(i, row) {
            resultHTML += row.FIRSTNAME + " " + row.LASTNAME + " " + row.ACCOUNT + " " + row.ID + "\n";
        });
        alert(resultHtml);
    }
});
```